# generate new files iteratively according to lines from another one

Tags: linux, shell, loops, awk, extract

I have two different files from which I want to extract some lines and generate new files. 
So my first file looks like this, file1.tsv:

```
A       B       C       D       E       Example  Set     Group
0       0       27      0       0       exA sub9    1
0       0       45      12      12      exA sub14   0
1       1       45      14      6       exA sub6    0
2       2       65      7       8       exA sub2    1
3       3       68      9       14      exA sub13   0
4       4       70      8       13      exA sub5    0
5       5       75      3       11      exA sub8    1
6       6       79      10      7       exA sub7    1
7       7       85      13      5       exA sub12   1
8       8       88      5       4       exA sub1    0
9       9       90      1       1       exA sub10   1
10      10      92      2       2       exA sub3    0
11      11      98      4       3       exA sub4    1
12      12      108     12      10      exA sub11   1
```

My second file is a vector file2.vec:

```
1 1:3.000 2:0.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub1, Bid=exA, group=1)
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:2.000 4:5.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub2, Bid=exA, group=2)
1 1:2.000 2:3.000 3:0.000 4:0.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub3, Bid=exA, group=1)
2 1:0.000 2:5.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub4, Bid=exA, group=2)
1 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub5, Bid=exA, group=1)
1 1:5.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:3.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub6, Bid=exA, group=1)
2 1:1.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:1.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub7, Bid=exA, group=2)
1 1:4.000 2:2.000 3:0.000 4:1.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub8, Bid=exA, group=1)
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub9, Bid=exA, group=2)
2 1:0.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:0.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub10, Bid=exA, group=2)
2 1:4.000 2:2.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub11, Bid=exA, group=2)
2 1:0.000 2:4.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub12, Bid=exA, group=2)
1 1:4.000 2:2.000 3:1.000 4:0.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub13, Bid=exA, group=1)
1 1:2.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:1.000 5:0.000 #(Aid=sub14, Bid=exA, group=1)
```

I want to use the data from the column 7 (header: Set) of file1.tsv to generate new files in which the corresponding lines from the file2.vec will be printed and for each iteration I want to add a new line to the previous output. So, for example, the first line (if we don’t count header) is sub9 in file1.tsv and the corresponding data from file2.vec can be linked using the Aid, so that the output will be:

```
out1.vec 
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000
```

I now want to have multiple outputs like this:

```
out2.vec 
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000
1 1:2.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:1.000 5:0.000

out3.vec 
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000
1 1:2.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:1.000 5:0.000
1 1:5.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:3.000 5:0.000

...
out4-13

out14.vec 
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000
1 1:2.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:1.000 5:0.000
1 1:5.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:3.000 5:0.000
2 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:2.000 4:5.000 5:0.000
1 1:4.000 2:2.000 3:1.000 4:0.000 5:0.000
1 1:0.000 2:1.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000
1 1:4.000 2:2.000 3:0.000 4:1.000 5:0.000
2 1:1.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:1.000 5:0.000
2 1:0.000 2:4.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000
1 1:3.000 2:0.000 3:0.000 4:4.000 5:0.000
2 1:0.000 2:0.000 3:1.000 4:0.000 5:0.000
1 1:2.000 2:3.000 3:0.000 4:0.000 5:0.000
2 1:0.000 2:5.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000
2 1:4.000 2:2.000 3:1.000 4:2.000 5:0.000
```

I have a directory with multiple files like file1.tsv and for each file I want to do the procedure described before. So I tried to write a shell script:

```
# first to extract column 7 
for filename in File; do
        listFile=$(basename "$filename" .tsv)-cmpdsList.tsv
        awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $7}}' $filename \
        > $listFile
done

# second to generate files containing lines from previously generated list
for line in $(cat $listFile); do
        echo "$line" > $line.vec
done

# add information corresponding to the compounds to generate vector file
for file in $line.vec; do
        output=$(basename "$line.vec" .vec)-output.vec
        gawk 'BEGIN {RS="\n"; ORS="\n"} (NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' $file RS="\n" $line.vec > $output
 done
```

But it only generates empty vector files. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea how you're getting the output you posted from the input you posted. Please explain the input to output mapping much better and make sure that the posted expected output is **exactly** the output expected from the posted sample input and not what you expect from different and/or additional input.

Comment: Are you picking lines from your second file based on some column value from first file?  If so, the connection is not clear.

Comment: I am using the order given in column 7 of file1 and linking it to the file2 through the Aid=sub[] given in the comment line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some comments on your code:

```
# first to extract column 7 
for filename in File; do
```

- `File` is a string. Perhaps you want a fileglob here?

```
        listFile=$(basename "$filename" .tsv)-cmpdsList.tsv
        awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $7}}' $filename \
        > $listFile
```

- The awk command can be shortened to: `awk 'NR>1 {print $7}' ...`
- It is safer to quote uses of `$listFile` : `"$listFile"`

```
done

# second to generate files containing lines from previously generated list
for line in $(cat $listFile); do
        echo "$line" > $line.vec
done
```

- If `$line` is `sub9` or somesuch, it cannot also be `out1`

```
# add information corresponding to the compounds to generate vector file
for file in $line.svm; do
        output=$(basename "$line.svm" .svm)-output.vec
        gawk 'BEGIN {RS="\n"; ORS="\n"} (NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' $file RS="\n" $line.svm > $output
 done
```

- Your samples don't include any `.svm` files so hard to interpret this code

---

### possible awk solution

Based on your `file1.tsv` and `file2.vec` (assuming the absent `1` at start of first line is a typo) and the description of outputs, a possible awk solution is:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR && NR>1 {
        n++
        aid[$7] = n
        next
    }
    NR!=FNR {
        pat = $7
        sub(/^#[(]Aid=/, "", pat)
        sub(/,$/, "", pat)
        sub(/ #.*$/, "", $0)
        line[ aid[pat] ] = $0
    }
    END {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            out = "out" i ".vec"
            printf "" > out
            for (j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                print line[j] >> out
            }
            close(out)
        }
    }
' file1.tsv file2.vec
```

- `NR==FNR ...` - pull out the id and map it to line number
- `NR!=FNR ...` - work out line from id in `$7`, strip trailing fields from `$0` and store
- `END ...` - for each line, output it and all preceding to appropriate output file
- `close` - close file after writing to avoid running out of file descriptors

Comment: Thank you and especially for the explanations and sorry for the typo, indeed I did some typos in my question.

Comment: I fixed a bug - `print > out` outputs `$0`. It can just be deleted (if output file is certain not to already exist), or replaced with `printf "" > out` as in the revised version. Also, `close` should have been in `i` loop, not the `j` loop